# what is maximum number of points of intersection between the diagonals of a convex octgon?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, permutations

What is the maximum number of points of intersection between the diagonals of a convex octagon
(8-vertex planar polygon)? Note that a polygon is said to be convex if the line segment joining any two points in its interior lies wholly in the interior of the polygon. Only points of intersection between diagonals that lie in the interior of the octagon are to be considered for this problem.

I am not getting how to think about this problem and is there any general solution for such problems?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357057/convex-polygon-with-18-vertices-and-points-of-intersection-of-the-diagonals ????  and http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3611964?uid=3738256&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102651377063

Comment: nice helpful link

Comment: There is a general solution, $\binom{n}{4}$. The argument in the example linked to by lab bhattacharjee, though ostensibly about an $18$-gon, is quite general.

Answer (score 6):

To explain André Nicolas's comment, for any group of $4$ vertices, there is one interior intersection of the diagonals. Thus, for each of the $\binom{n}{4}$ choice of $4$ vertices, there is one intersection. Therefore, the maximum number of intersections (when there are no coincident intersections) is
$$
\binom{n}{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The general solution as mentioned above is only valid for n odd. For more information, you can read this paper http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf

Comment: Are you talking about $\binom{n}{4}$?  Why only for odd $n$? If the octagon is not regular, then that number is the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

for n-gon, it is n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/24
for octagon it is 8*7*6*5/24 = 70

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).