# Finding number of diagonals of polygon knowing number of points of intersection

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In a polygon, no three diagonals are concurrent. If the total number of points of intersection of the diagonals be 70, then the number of diagonals in the polygon is:

**My attempt:**

Let the number of diagonals in the polygon be $n$. Then, the number of points of intersection given that no three are concurrent will be ${ n \choose 2 } = 70$. However, this has no solutions. I understand this may be wrong since some of the diagonals may be parallel to each other, hence having no point of intersection.

How do I approach this problem? Hints or solutions are appreciated.

**EDIT:** @user3733558's answer is correct and matches what is given in my book, and I understand the approach used as well.

However, I'm still uncertain as to why the method I was using is incorrect, so could someone help me understand where my thinking is flawed?

Comment: Are we assuming the polygon is convex? [$n$-choose-$2$ is clearly wrong, e.g., a square, $n=4$, doesn't have six intersection points]

Comment: @GerryMyerson for a square, $n=2$ since I'm defining $n$ as the number of diagonals, not sides. so it would give ${2 \choose 2}$ which is correct, a square's diagonals only intersect at one point, So I still don't understand why this is wrong

Comment: The flaw in your attempt is that not every pair of diagonals intersects. If you pick four vertices, there are three ways to pair them up to make sides or diagonals, but only one of those pairings will intersect. That is why there is a one-to-one correspondence between intersections and the number of ways to choose 4 vertices, but not between pairs of diagonals and intersections.

Comment: Intersection points do not correspond in a one-to-one manner with pairs of diagonals. Two diagonals might have no intersection, and some pairs have none, so the number of pairs of diagonals is greater than the number of intersection points. Intersection points, however, do correspond in a one-to-one manner with 4-subsets of vertices (assuming no three or more vertices are collinear), using the diagonals of the quadrilateral formed by the four vertices.

Comment: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1552404).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every intersection maps uniquely to a set of $4$ distinct points. Therefore ${n \choose 4} = 70$, which implies that there are $n=8$ vertices, and consequently, there are ${n \choose 2} = 28$ diagonals in the polygon.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how “[e]very intersection maps uniquely to a set of 4 distinct points,” I’ll add that for a point of intersection (in the interior of the polygon), that set is the vertices at the ends of the two intersecting diagonals. Not only does every interior intersection determine a set of four vertices, every set of four vertices determines an intersection point. Form a quadrilateral from the four vertices and the intersection point is the intersection of the diagonals of the quadrilateral. (Presumably the polygon has no three or more collinear vertices.)

Comment: that's the correct answer, and I understand the logic here, however I'm not sure why my method was incorrect

Comment: $\binom82$ counts sides as well as diagonals.  There are $20$ diagonals.

Comment: @HridaiKhurana : you were trying to go from "number of intersections" directly to "number of diagonals". But this is bound to fail, because diagonals have 0 to many intersections. The only way is to derive the number of vertices/edges of the polygon, and then the number of diagonals.

Comment: @saulspatz agreed, the problem statement is quite unclear, so it can be interpreted in different ways.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I'm still uncertain as to why the method I was using is incorrect, so could someone help me understand where my thinking is flawed?

The problem is that not all pairs of diagonals intersect. For example, if you have a convex hexagon ABCDEF diagonals AC and DF do not intersect

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem possible as stated. Suppose that the polygon has $m$ vertices.  Each vertex lies on $m-3$ diagonals, one joining it to each vertex other than itself and its two neighbors.  That is, $m-3$ diagonals concur at each vertex.  If $m-3<3$ then $m\leq5$.  A pentagon has $5$ diagonals, and for $\binom n2\geq70$ we need $n\geq13$.

Perhaps the problem should say, "No three are concurrent, except at the vertices."  In that case, suppose the polygon has $m$ vertices, and that no diagonals are parallel.  Then the polygon has $$d=\frac{m(m-3)}2$$ diagonals.  There are $\binom d2$ pairs of diagonals but this would count each vertex $\binom{m-3}2$ times, once for each pair of diagonals passing through it.  Therefore the number of points of intersection is $$\binom d2-m\left(\binom{m-3}2-1\right)$$  Setting $m=7$ gives $56$ and setting $m=8$ gives $118$, so there's no solution without parallel diagonals.  In that case, it's hard to know how to find a solution, let alone show that it's unique.

I originally did the problem incorrectly.  I said, "Each vertex is counted $m-3$ times, once for each diagonal that passes through it, so that the number of points of intersection is $\binom d2-m(m-4)$."  In this case, setting $m=7$ gives $70$.

I suspect that this is the solution intended, and that whoever composed the problem made the same mistake that I did.

Comment: this was my thinking, however @user3733558 's answer matches what is given in the book, and the logic checks out, so I'm led to believe the way I was thinking was flawed in some way

Comment: @HridaiKhurana I'm sure that that answer is what's intended, but note that it doesn't count the vertices as intersection points.  With $m=8$ we have $d=20$.  There are $5$ diagonals at each vertex, so if we exclude the vertices as intersection points, we get $\binom{20}2-8\binom52=70$.

Comment: you're right, I see how it counts only points of intersection inside the polygon. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @HridaiKhurana Now I'm confused.  You're right; user3733558's answer only counts intersections inside the polygon (assuming it to be convex.)  But my calculation is intended to count intersections both inside and outside the polygon.  I'm going to have to think about this some more.

Comment: @HridaiKhurana I don't think I'm fully awake yet.  $\binom{20}2-8\binom52=110$ not $70$.  There must be $40$ intersections outside the polygon.  I'll see if I can show it along the lines we were using.  If so, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @HridaiKhurana We were forgetting the definition of "diagonal."  It's the line segment joining two non-adjacent vertices, so it makes no sense to talk about two diagonals intersecting outside a convex quadrilateral.  We were working with the lines formed by producing the diagonals, and trying to answer the wrong question.

Comment: And nowhere has OP agreed that the polygon is meant to be convex, even though I specifically asked about that in the very first comment on the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, although I think that's more due to whoever posed the problem, which is, I think, stated very sloppily.