# Confusion regarding intersection of diagonals

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In a heptagon not more than two diagonals intersect at any point other than the vertices, then what should be the number of points of intersection of the diagonals is (excluding the vertices of this heptagon)?

Is the answer $35$ or $49$

$35$ approach will be using $nC4 = 7C4 = 35$

$49$ approach will be
$14C2 - 7\cdot4C2$
$14C2$ total possibilities of diagonals

Total no of diagonal of heptagon $= 14$
No of intersection of diagonal other than at vertices$= 14C2$
But 4 diagonals arises from a single vertex . They will never intersect
So we subtract $4C2$
And there are total 7 vertices. So we subtract $7× 4C2$
Answer $= 14C2-7×4C2 = 49$

Which one is correct please help

Comment: I like the 35, there must be a one to one mapping between intersection points and combinations of four vertices

Comment: This is closely related to (and possibly answered by answers to) [what is maximum number of points of intersection between the diagonals of a convex octgon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494618/what-is-maximum-number-of-points-of-intersection-between-the-diagonals-of-a-conv) and [Convex polygon with 18 vertices and points of intersection of the diagonals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357057/convex-polygon-with-18-vertices-and-points-of-intersection-of-the-diagonals).

Answer (score 5):

Your first approach is correct because for any $4$ vertices you choose you can have one and only one pair of diagonals that intersect at a point thus getting a one to one mapping between intersection points and combinations of four vertices (as mentioned by @WW1)

Your second approach fails because you didn't account for diagonals that don't intersect even though they do not have a common vertex. You can consider the following example,
[image]